# Check the checkbox on a web page from Outlook

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I am having trouble with the checking of a check box from a web page. I have tried:

```
    Do
         ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
    Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

     Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document


   For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If oHTML_Element.Type = "orderById" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next


    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    oBrowser.Visible = True

    'oBrowser.Document.forms(0).all("tdFilter").Item(0).Click
    oBrowser.Document.forms(0).all("tdFilter").Click
    'IE.Document.forms(0).all("tdFilter").CheckBox = True

     ' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

end this is the source code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the reason for the loop:

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "orderById" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
```

Also, "orderById is an id, so should you not just reference it as:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("orderById")
```

Similarly you could set the checkbox with:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("tdFilter").Checked = True
```

If it is not working, inspect your elements, make sure you have the right names, make sure you do not have duplicate ids and also check how your events are triggering.